# Multiprocessors vs Multithreading in the context of PThreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, hardware, multiprocessing

I have an application level (PThreads) question regarding choice of hardware and its impact on software development.

I have working multi-threaded code tested well on a multi-core single CPU box.

I am trying to decide what to purchase for my next machine:

- A 6-core single CPU box
- A 4-core dual CPU box

**My question is, if I go for the dual CPU box, will that impact the porting of my code in a serious way?  Or can I just allocate more threads and let the OS handle the rest?**

In other words, is multiprocessor programming any different from (single CPU) multithreading in the context of a PThreads application?

*I thought it would make no difference at this level, but when configuring a new box, I noticed that one has to buy separate memory for each CPU.  That's when I hit some cognitive dissonance.*

**More Detail Regarding the Code (for those who are interested):**  I read a ton of data from disk into a huge chunk of memory (~24GB soon to be more), then I spawn my threads.  That initial chunk of memory is "read-only" (enforced by my own code policies) so I don't do any locking for that chunk.  I got confused as I was looking at 4-core dual CPU boxes - they seem to require separate memory.  In the context of my code, I have no idea what will happen "under the hood" if I allocate a bunch of extra threads.  Will the OS copy my chunk of memory from one CPU's memory bank to another?  **This would impact how much memory I would have to buy (raising the cost for this configuration).**  The ideal situation (cost-wise and ease-of-programming-wise) is to have the dual CPU share one large bank of memory, but if I understand correctly, this may not be possible on the new Intel dual core MOBOs (like the HP ProLiant ML350e)?

Comment: @pst - I was looking at the new HP ProLiant ML350e which uses the E5-2400 series.  It would be nice to use one large pool of memory (to reduce costs), but HP's configuration/order-form seems to require separate memory (maybe I'm using it wrong?).

Comment: @kfme04 interesting - Didn't even know x86/x64 had such a concept. Here is a [related post on hardware stack](http://serverfault.com/questions/39200/server-motherboards-memory-per-cpu) ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modern CPUs<sup>1</sup> handle RAM locally and use a separate channel<sup>2</sup> to communicate between them.  This is a consumer-level version of the NUMA architecture, created for supercomputers more than a decade ago.

The idea is to avoid a shared bus (the old FSB) that can cause heavy contention because it's used by every core to access memory.  As you add more NUMA cells, you get higher bandwidth.  The downside is that memory becomes non-uniform from the point of view of the CPU: some RAM is faster than others.

Of course, modern OS schedulers are NUMA-aware, so they try to reduce the migration of a task from one cell to another.  Sometimes it's okay to move from one core to another in the same socket; sometimes there's a whole hierarchy specifying which resources (1-,2-,3-level cache, RAM channel, IO, etc) are shared and which aren't, and that determines if there would be a penalty or not by moving the task.  Sometimes it can determine that waiting for the right core would be pointless and it's better to shovel the whole thing to another socket....

In the vast majority of cases, it's best to leave the scheduler do what it knows best.  If not, you can play around with `numactl`.

As for the specific case of a given program; the best architecture depends heavily in the level of resource sharing between threads.  If each thread has its own playground and mostly works alone within it, a smart enough allocator would prioritize local RAM, making it less important on which cell each thread happens to be.

If, on the other hand, objects are allocated by one thread, processed by another and consumed by a third; performance would suffer if they're not on the same cell.  You could try to create small thread groups and limit heavy sharing within the group, then each group could go on a different cell without problem.

The worst case is when all threads participate in a great orgy of data sharing.  Even if you have all your locks and processes well debugged, there won't be any way to optimize it to use more cores than what are available on a cell.  It might even be best to limit the whole process to just use the cores in a single cell, effectively wasting the rest.

<sup>1</sup> by modern, I mean any AMD-64bit chip, and Nehalem or better for Intel.

<sup>2</sup> AMD calls this channel HyperTransport, and Intel name is QuickPath Interconnect

**EDIT:**

You mention that you initialize "a big chunk of read-only memory".  And then spawn a lot of threads to work on it.  If each thread works on its own part of that chunk, then it would be a lot better if you initialize it *on the thread*, after spawning it.  That would allow the threads to spread to several cores, and the allocator would choose local RAM for each, a much more effective layout.  Maybe there's some way to hint the scheduler to migrate away the threads as soon as they're spawned, but I don't know the details.

**EDIT 2:**

If your data is read verbatim from disk, without any processing, it might be advantageous to use `mmap` instead of allocating a big chunk and `read()`ing.  There are some common advantages:

1. No need to preallocate RAM.
2. The `mmap` operation is almost instantaneous and you can start using it.  The data will be read lazily as needed.
3. The OS can be way smarter than you when choosing between application, `mmap`ed RAM, buffers and cache.
4. it's less code!
5. Non needed data won't be read, won't use up RAM.
6. You can specifically mark as read-only.  Any bug that tries to write will cause a coredump.
7. Since the OS knows it's read-only, it can't be 'dirty', so if the RAM is needed, it will simply discard it, and reread when needed.

but in this case, you also get:

- Since data is read lazily, each RAM page would be chosen *after* the threads have spread on all available cores; this would allow the OS to choose pages close to the process.

So, I think that if two conditions hold:

- the data isn't processed in any way between disk and RAM
- each part of the data is read (mostly) by one single thread, not touched by all of them.

then, just by using `mmap`, you should be able to take advantage of machines of any size.

If each part of the data is read by more than one single thread, maybe you could identify which threads will (mostly) share the same pages, and try to hint the scheduler to keep these in the same NUMA cell.

Comment: +1 for a great, detailed answer!  I will need to read it several times to digest it, but this answer is making me lean towards a single 6-core CPU box.  Just one question:  in terms of data-sharing, I will be reading one huge (many 10's of GBs) of chunk of read-only data (so no locking).  Will this kind of "sharing" preclude any gains from using a second CPU?

Comment: I >definitely do not< want to play with numactl!!!  But it's good to know it's there for the OS to manage.

Comment: Is your "EDIT answer" an optimization for multiprocessors?  If so, this is the kind of thing I want to avoid (not ready to complicate the application to that level yet).  If it is true that I need to optimize to take advantage of multiprocessors (when using a chunk of memory this big), then I will probably go for single CPU/more cores.  If it's a simple case of asking "how many cores are available", so I can pick the number of threads, that's fine.  Anything beyond that level of optimization, I would prefer to avoid (for now).

Comment: Further to the very detailed answer above,  synchronisation between threads can get expensive with NUMA architectures.  The Mutex you are using to protect shared data has in its implementation a lock-count whose modification and successive visibility to a remote core must be atomic by some mechanism.  This is inevitably cheaper between adjacent cores on the same die than two cores on different ones. 

Key to making software performant on big SMP systems is avoiding locking.  This is typically achieved a loosely coupled architecture  using message passing and queuing.

Comment: @Marko, I think you're right, message passing can be more appropriate on NUMA machines; unfortunately I think it's usually implemented on top of traditional locks.  And I don't know if any common OS have any kind of 'directed locks', the usual lock implementation starts by invalidating a full cache line across all caches on all cores, incurring in heavy latency costs.

Comment: @kfmfe04, yes, i think the optimal use of all resources would be to have the threads spread on most cores on all sockets; but each thread processing data on memory close to it.  Since modern allocators are NUMA-aware, if the threads spread first and then you allocate RAM, it should be close to optimal.

Comment: @kfmfe04; but now you've said that the data is read from disk, so my just using `mmap` instead of `read()`, you get the 'allocate after spreading' because data is read lazily; and you won't depend on making a good choice on allocators, since it would be only at the RAM page level by the virtual memory subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

For the x86 boxes you're looking at, the fact that memory is physically wired to different CPU sockets is an implementation detail.  Logically, the total memory of the machine appears as one large pool - your wouldn't need to change your application code for it to run *correctly* across both CPUs.

Performance, however, is another matter.  There is a speed penalty for cross-socket memory access, so the unmodified program may not run to its full potential.

Unfortunately, it's hard to say ahead of time whether your code will run faster on the 6-core, one-node box or the 8-core, two-node box.  Even if we could see your code, it would ultimately be an educated guess.  A few things to consider:

- The cross-socket memory access penalty only kicks in on a cache miss, so if your program has good cache behaviour then NUMA won't hurt you much;
- If your threads are all writing to private memory regions and you're limited by write bandwidth to memory, then the dual-socket machine will end up helping;
- If you're compute-bound rather than memory-bandwidth-bound then 8 cores is likely better than 6;
- If your performance is bounded by cache read misses then the 6 core single-socket box starts to look better;
- If you have a lot of lock contention or writes to shared data then again this tends to advise towards the single-socket box.

There's a lot of variables, so the best thing to do is to ask your HP reseller for loaner machines matching the configurations you're considering.  You can then test your application out, see where it performs best and order your hardware accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, it's hard to give a detailed answer.  However, hopefully the following will help you frame the problem.

If your thread code is proper (e.g. you properly lock shared resources), you should not experience any bugs introduced by the change of hardware architecture.  Improper threading code can sometimes be masked by the specifics of how a specific platform handles things like CPU cache access/sharing.

You may experience a change in application performance per equivalent core due to differing approaches to memory and cache management in the single chip, multi core vs. multi chip alternatives.

Specifically if you are looking at hardware that has separate memory per CPU, I would assume that each thread is going to be locked to the CPU it starts on (otherwise, the system would have to incur significant overhead to move a thread's memory to memory dedicated to a different core).  That may reduce overall system efficiency depending on your specific situation.  However, separate memory per core also means that the different CPUs do not compete with each other for a given cache line (the 4 cores on each of the dual CPUs will still potentially compete for cache lines, but that is less contention than if 6 cores are competing for the same cache lines).

This type of cache line contention is called *False Sharing*.  I suggest the following read to understand if that may be an issue you are facing

http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206?pgno=3

Bottom line is, application behavior should be stable (other than things that naturally depend on the details of thread scheduling) if you followed proper thread development practices, but performance could go either way depending on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Eric, ty for your detailed response.  It seems, from your response, that there is multiprocessor hardware that can share one big pool of memory?  Is this true?  If so, I suppose it depends on the MOBO/Bios?  I am concerned because my threads share one big chunk of read-only memory (no locking because I don't spawn threads until after the memory is initialized) - I was wondering how this would look in the context of dual-CPU with separate memory banks.

Comment: @Javier answered your comment very well.